# How do I manipulate Time.timeScale with the character controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do something like that prototype game SuperHot, where 'time moves only when you move'.

The methods I can think of involve manipulating Time.timeScale with the input, or the character controller's velocity.

The following is how I did it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TimeMechanic : MonoBehaviour {
private float targetScale;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    targetScale = 0.02f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    Time.timeScale = targetScale; //setting the timeScale
    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") != 0)
    {
        targetScale += 0.03f; //incrementing the variable by 0.03
        if (targetScale > 1f)
        {
            targetScale = 1f; //limits the variable to 1 at max
        }
    }
    else
    {
        targetScale -= 0.03f; //decrementing the variable by 0.03
        if (targetScale < 0.02f)
        {
            targetScale = 0.02f; //limits variable to 0.02 at min
        }
    }
    Debug.Log (targetScale);
}
```

}

My questions:

1. Is manipulating the timeScale with the character controller's velocity viable?
2. Are there things I should improve in this code?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your algorithms. In fact when you reduce the `timeScale` it will have a circular dependency. Depending on the `Input` will be better but it will depend on the look and feel you expect.

> When timeScale is set to zero the game is basically paused if all your
>   functions are frame rate independent.
>
> Except for realtimeSinceStartup, timeScale affects all the time and
>   delta time measuring variables of the Time class.
>
> If you lower timeScale it is recommended to also lower
>   Time.fixedDeltaTime by the same amount.
>
> FixedUpdate functions will not be called when timeScale is set to
>   zero.

As `Physics` are most preferred with a `FixedUpdate` it is necessary to note the above points unless your game will have a lot of irregularities.